# DisallowedRedirect (Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol) Django

Tags: django, authentication

I am getting DisallowedRedirect error when i am logging user in
The two views are

```
def login(request):
    c={}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    form=LoginForm()
    errors=()
    c['form']=form
    c['errors']=errors
    return render(request,'news/login.html',c)

def auth_view(request):
    username=request.POST.get('username','')
    password=request.POST.get('password','')
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('news:home',request)
    else:
        form=LoginForm()
        errors=('Invalid Username or Password',)
        return render(request,'news/login.html', {'form':form,'errors':errors})
```

Comment: where exactly is the error happenning? line number?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

instead of

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('news:home',request)
```

this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:home'))
```

or

```
return redirect('news:home')
```

or

```
return redirect(reverse('news:home'))
```

Comment: but why does django need 'reverse' ?? (In this situation)

Comment: Because HttpResponseRedirect consider `news` as URL protocol, not as Django path name.

Answer (score 10):

HttpResponseRedirect.allowed_schemes.append('news')

Comment: I wish I wasn't ignoring this for so long :)) it was exactly what I needed to be able to redirect to (myapp://)

Comment: Looks like a hack but there is no other good way I could find, the lib doesn't expose an override for the response class

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the current answers if you want to redirect to an custom scheme, you can use following code:

```
class CustomSchemeRedirect(HttpResponsePermanentRedirect):
    allowed_schemes = ['tg']


def redirect(request):
    return CustomSchemeRedirect('tg://resolve?domain=durov')
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that when you get this error you have the correct scheme supplied in front of your URL. By default the `django.http.HttpResponseRedirect` does not allow redirects to URLs that don't start with one of the following schemes:

- http
- https
- ftp

So if the URL you supply is, for example, `localhost:8000` make sure you change it to `http://localhost:8000` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that apart from enabling the redirect, nowadays Safari won't open your redirected deep links unless you do the work outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

1. Add the url path into your Django app:

```
path('.well-known/apple-app-site-association', views.web.links.appleAppSiteAssociation, name='.well-known/apple-app-site-association'),
```

2. The view should return a JSON response:

```
def appleAppSiteAssociation(request_):
   """
   Tell Apple that certain URL patterns can open the app
   :param request_:
   :return:
   """
   json = {
     "applinks": {
         "details": [
              {
                "appIDs": ["MY.APP.BUNDLEID"],
                "components": [
                  {
                     "#": "no_universal_links",
                     "exclude": True,
                     "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
                  },
                  {
                     "/": "/dataUrl=*",
                     "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /dataUrl="
                  },

                ]
              }
          ]
      },
      "webcredentials": {
         "apps": ["MY.APP.BUNDLEID"]
      },
   }

   return JsonResponse(json)
```

3. Add the `webcredentials:MYPROTOCOL` into the Associated Domains in XCode